# How to run multiple scripts in parallel

Tags: bash, shell-script, perl, parallelism

I have one bash script which calls the same perl script in a serial way. The bash script is used to collect the overall results, while the perl script collects the results of my simulations for the given attributes.

The bash script looks as follows:

```
mkdir ./results/csv     && \
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F reach results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/reach.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F roundTrip results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/RT.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F downlink results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/DL.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F clusters results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/clusters.csv
```

Collecting the results by calling one perl script at a time is really long; I am looking for a way which would allow me to call the different variations of the perl script within the bash script in parallel. Is there a way to achieve this in bash?

Just to clarify, I don't want the commands which call the perl script to be dependent on each other in any way. I want all of them to start at the same point in time, as if I had 4 separate bash-terminals each executing one of these commands.

Similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644991/running-several-scripts-in-parallel-bash-script

Answer (score 5):

If you have `gnu parallel` installed, you could make a script with just the commands, e.g.:

```
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F reach results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/reach.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F roundTrip results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/RT.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F downlink results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/DL.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F clusters results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/clusters.csv
```

and then run them in parallel:

```
mkdir ./results/csv && parallel :::: myscript.sh
```

Alternatively, invoking the command and using `{}` - the default replacement string:

```
mkdir ./results/csv && parallel ../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F {} \
results/Heterogeneous*.vec '>' ./results/csv/{}.csv ::: reach roundTrip downlink clusters
```

would run the following commands in parallel:

```
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F reach results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/reach.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F roundTrip results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/roundTrip.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F downlink results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/downlink.csv
../perlscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F clusters results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/clusters.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
../_Cscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F reach results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/reach.csv &
../_Cscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F roundTrip results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/RT.csv &
../_Cscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F downlink results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/DL.csv &
../_Cscripts/v2csv.pl -v -F clusters results/Heterogeneous*.vec > ./results/csv/clusters.csv &
wait
```

The & puts the program in background. wait waits for them to stop if you care.

Comment: what would happen if there was no wait?

Comment: @Cross without the `wait`, the script wouldn't wait for all the scripts to finish before it itself ended.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think the script would just end and the processes would just be running in the background. If that is what you want, precede each command with nohup and be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following syntax:

```
mkdir ./results/csv && (script0 & script1 &)
```

This will run the scripts in the background, not waiting for them to finish. The parentheses introduce a subshell group (so that no script will be run if the mkdir command fails) and the `&` requests background execution (returning control to the outer shell right away).

Comment: how does is differ from the solution given by Robert Jacobs? asking just for understanding purposes

Comment: It's hardly different from the other answer... there was no answer posted when I started typing mine.

Comment: but you don't have the `wait` and he does not use paratheses

Comment: That's right; the parentheses are for grouping, so that none of the scripts get run if `mkdir` fails (one could avoid spawning a sub-shell here, though it's unlikely to be a performance killer if your scripts take long enough to run that you care about running them in parallel), and, without the call to `wait`, this script will return almost instantly, letting the scripts run in the background. This is a matter of subjective preference; if you want to be blocked until all jobs have completed, then use `wait`. Otherwise you can use `jobs` to see if your script is still running.